# What is the sound for ज्ञ in Sanskrit?

Tags: sanskrit

Wikipedia has this:

```
ɟɲ  ज्ञ jñ  roughly like argue
```

But those 3 writings all conflict with one another, so what is the correct pronunciation?

Comment: 'jñ' A mix of ज् and ञ as spoken by Tamil, Tulu or Malayali Brahmins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the [gj] pronunciation of ज्ञ is a modern regional pronunciation associated with Hindi-speaking areas, and doesn't have a classical pedigree (e.g. Panini). ɟɲ vs. jñ are not different pronunciations, they are transliterations (the former being IPA, the latter being traditional Sanskrit transliteration).

Comment: What is a good transliteration for pronunciation then?

Comment: A good transliteration is *jñ* – it's standard. If you can pronounce IPA [ɟɲ], aim for that. Practical spelling and technical transcription are two different things. You may need some pronunciation coaching from your nearby fluent native speakers (*ahem*) if you know any. Plain English "jn" is close enough, IMO.